# ORA-06553 character set name is not recognized

Tags: database, oracle

I have changed oracle database's `NLS_CHARACTERSET` from `WE8MSWIN1252` to`AL32UTF8` as described [here](http://riaddba.blogspot.de/2013/02/how-to-change-database-character-set.html)

Now when I run database commands, I get the following error:

> [ERROR]: Exception occurred, terminating. java.sql.SQLException:
> ORA-06552: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated ORA-06553:
> PLS-553: character set name is not recognized

Any idea?

Comment: just curious, why did you try to change the character set? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Oracle provides a [migration tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/globalization/dmu/overview/index.html)  for this.  Not sure what that website's code will do to your db.

Comment: Very bad, restore your database from backup and do it according to the official guidelines provided by Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Bad idea. If you already have data on it, you'll get it corrupt (this [thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2411993) talks about the same thing). That exercise you found is valid for empty instances.

Mind the [official guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011) to do a charset migration and decide according to your scenario. It might require to export data as INSERT sentences and execute after changing charset -always remember to set `NLS_LANG` accordingly (for utf8 it is *American.America.UTF8*) as environment variable where you are using SQL*plus, tho-

Comment: Hmmm I tried to redo this change but I get the same error. What shall I do? I do not really need my data on my local system. The goal is to be able to store character like greek letters